# How can I trigger an event when I hit enter?

Tags: jquery

```
    $('#enter').click(function (){
        var query = $('#search').val();
        $('body').removeHighlight().highlight(query);
    });
```

Above is the code I use for an on page instant search. How can I add an event listener so that when I hit enter it automatically triggers the .click() function as soon as I hit enter so the user doesn't have to manually have to click on the #enter element. Also if I hit enter it can't affect the value of search field. It'd be helpful if the code was in jQuery.

Comment: Is the `#enter` element in a form?

Comment: You might want to use [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: Wrapping your input in a `form` and then binding to the `submit` event of the form might be a simpler alternative (the browser handles numerous events that constitute form submission, including hitting enter, pressing submit, etc.).

Comment: I already tried the .submit but it refreshes the page

Comment: my code below will work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the keypress event on jquery to trigger the event.

```
$('#enter').keypress(function (e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
       var query = $('#search').val();
       $('body').removeHighlight().highlight(query);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you meant <kbd>Enter</kbd> press from `search` textbox. Try below and let me know if this is something you want,

```
$('#search').keydown(function (e) {       
   if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#enter').click();
   }
});
```

Try changing your query function like below,

```
$('#enter').click(function (){
    var query = $('#search').val();
    if ($.trim(query) != '')  {
      $('body').removeHighlight().highlight(query);  
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not letting me type in the search field

Comment: Works now but if left blank the page freezes up.

Comment: Wait can I set an if statement saying if query = "" and then disable the click

Comment: @PacoDev Check the query condition that you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean if(query == "") {deactivate field here}

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment, you can use [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) like this

```
$('#search').keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $('#enter').trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Comment: works but causes my page to slow down if it's blank an hit enter and even freezes the page